# C++ polymorphic pointers created in for loop refer to the same thing, is this because I'm not using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have a base class in my program and two subclasses.
I'm totally new to c++ and don't 
I have something  akin to the following loop:

```
baseclass * arr[10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (some condition) {
    SubclassA subA;
    subA = SubclassA(stuff);
    arr[i] = &subA;
   }
   else if (some other condition) {
    SubclassB subA;
    subB = SubclassB(stuff);
    arr[i] = &subB;
   }
}
```

when I run my code and first create a SubclassA and assign its address to my array. 
However I'm finding the following is occuring: after the previous step, when I later in the loop create a SubclassB, the SubclassB for some reason is being made at the same memory location that my SubclassA was at: it's overwriting my first object completely and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are storing the address of a local variable that goes out of scope.

Comment: You have to use "new" operator to allocate memory dynamically

Comment: Learn and then use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<baseclass>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ `subA = SubclassA(stuff);` doesn't mean to allocate and create a totally new object, and then assign a reference to it. `subA` is a local object and will disappear as soon as the enclosing `}` is reached. You can't store off its address into your array.

You need to actually allocate new objects with `new` and preferably use a smart pointer to control ownership and lifetime:

```
Typedef std::array<std::unique_ptr<baseclass>, 10> ArrType;
ArrType arr;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (some condition)
    {
        arr[i] = ArrType::value_type(new SubclassA(stuff));
    }
    else if (some other condition)
    {
        arr[i] = ArrType::value_type(new SubclassB(stuff));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Neil Kirk I didn't see anything in the question that would specifically indicate a non-C-array solution (like allocating the array in the heap in addition to the objects) so I left it as close to the original as possible.

Comment: `std::array` is almost always better than C array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pointers and create `new` objects to add to the array instead of using local objects.

```
baseclass * arr[10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (some condition) {
    arr[i] = new SubclassA(stuff);
   }
   else if (some other condition) {
    arr[i] = new SubclassB(stuff);
   }
}
```

And don't forget you need to go through the array and delete the pointers when you are done.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   delete arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use new in your subclass

```
baseclass * arr[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
        if (some condition) {
        SubclassA subA =  new SubclassA(stuff);
        arr[i] = subA;    
        }    
        else if (some other condition) {
        SubclassB subB = new SubclassB(stuff);
        arr[i] = subB;    
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are storing pointers to local variables `subA` and `subB`. When the variables go out of scope the objects are deleted and the pointers are left dangling.

To fix it you must use dynamic memory allocation. It is recommended to manage the dynamically allocated memory with smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<baseclass>> arr;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (some condition) {
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<SubclassA>());
  } else if (some other condition) {
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<SubclassB>());
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `make_unique` is C++14 so you may still need to use a bare `new` expression.